# What does `get` mean in an object literal?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototype

Below is a snippet from Chrome Developer's tool:

```
WebInspector.DOMStorage.prototype = {
    get id()
    {
        return this._id;
    },

    get domain()
    {
        return this._domain;
    },

    get isLocalStorage()
    {
        return this._isLocalStorage;
    },

    getEntries: function(callback)
    {
        DOMStorageAgent.getDOMStorageEntries(this._id, callback);
    },

    setItem: function(key, value, callback)
    {
        DOMStorageAgent.setDOMStorageItem(this._id, key, value, callback);
    },

    removeItem: function(key, callback)
    {
        DOMStorageAgent.removeDOMStorageItem(this._id, key, callback);
    }
}
```

`WebInspector.DOMStorage` is a function and in the code above are its prototypes. The most strange for me is the following method: `get id()` or `get` something - I checked that into the object prototype only `removeItem`, `getEntries` and `setItem` are recognized. What about the others?

Answer (score 3):

Those are getters. If you have an instance of `DOMStorage` you can do:

```
var domain = inst.domain;
```

but you can't assign to it (or you can but the value doesn't get changed):

```
inst.domain = 4; #doesnt change inst.domain
```

See [this link](http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/28/getters-and-setters-with-javascript-code-samples-and-demos/) for more info about it. Only some browsers support it.

Comment: Please note that accessors have been standardized in ECMAScript 5, so most modern browsers support them. That is, [FF2+, Safari3+, IE9, Chrome, Opera9.5+](http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html#regular-getters-and-setters)